# Merge list haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have two lists for example:
`[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I want to merge them to `[2,4,6,8,10]`.
Is there an easy way to do this in haskell since there aint traditional loops?
Assume that both lists will be same size

Comment: Use `zipWith`...

Comment: Arguably, there is an easy way to do it *because* there aren't traditional loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell doesn't have traditional loops, but it does have recursion:

```
foo :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
foo [] [] = []
foo (x:xs) (y:ys) = x+y : foo xs ys
```

Or, as suggested by Willem Van Onsem, you can just use the function `zipWith`:

```
foo = zipWith (+)
```

Note that if you don't specify the exact type of `foo`, it will be infered as

```
foo :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: If the lists have a length mismatch `zipwith (+)` will handle it fine by truncating the longer list but the recursive implementation will error as it isn't checking for that case.

Comment: The fix would be to replace the single base case with two base cases `foo [] _ = []` and `foo _ [] = []`, but at that point you have pretty much just reimplemented `zipWith (=)`.